# iMacros: user defined variables within !COLn?

Tags: javascript, csv, imacros

I'm looking for a possibility to let a user choose what column of his CSV input the script should use in the `{{!COLn}}` part.

```
PROMPT "Please enter CSV column:" !VAR1

SET !DATASOURCE C:\User\Desktop\Test\testsource.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 100
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{i}}

URL GOTO=http://www.somewebsite.com
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:123:<SP>*
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=* CONTENT={{!COLn}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD ATTR=TXT:{{!COLn}}
```

n in `!COLn` should be set to the user defined variable `!VAR1`. I got now clue how! Thanks for all advices.

Comment: I would suggest, if possible to place all your COL into one COL and then using the Datasource loop function to define at which line your data should be taken from.
However on iMacros forum is a little workaround http://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=26316

Answer (score 1):

Here is a macro that must work fine with the first 5 columns of your datasource:

```
PROMPT "Please enter CSV column:" !VAR1

SET !DATASOURCE C:\User\Desktop\Test\testsource.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 100
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{i}}

SET row "'{{!COL1}}', '{{!COL2}}', '{{!COL3}}', '{{!COL4}}', '{{!COL5}}'"
SET col EVAL("var col = eval('[{{row}}]'); col[{{!VAR1}} - 1];")

URL GOTO=http://www.somewebsite.com
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:123:<SP>*
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=* CONTENT={{col}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD ATTR=TXT:{{col}}
```

You should manually edit the line `SET row ...` so that it would represent the whole row, i.e. contain all the `'{{!COLn}}'` separated with commas. BTW, if the number of columns is big or/and changing often, I advise to write an additional macro that will generate this string for you.

Answer (score 1):

Not a simple answer but you can create a php website (even for free), add a NXM matrix/dataset to it and have a simple url interface www.mysite.com/index.php?loop={{!LOOP}}&col={{!VAR1}} to return the value you want