# iMacros read column .csv from choice of user between 1 to 10

Tags: csv, imacros

I have a question that is similar to the following link:
[iMacros: user defined variables within !COLn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38498006/imacros-user-defined-varibles-within-coln)
I've tried that apply to my script (bellow) but error, like this:

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal, line 12 (Error code: -1001)
```

line 12 is :

```
SET col EVAL("var col=eval('[{{row}}]'); col[{{!VAR1}} - 1];")
```

The following is my full script with the same question, NEED TO ENTRY TEXT FROM .CSV FILE, BUT iMacros READ COLUMN IS FROM CHOICE OF USER BETWEEN 1 to 10.

```
VERSION BUILD=8871104 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 10
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
SET !DATASOURCE c:\option\abc.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE 2

PROMPT "Please enter CSV column:\n\n1. Red \n2. Green \n3. Blue \n4.so on" !VAR1

SET row "'{{!COL1}}', '{{!COL2}}', '{{!COL3}}', '{{!COL4}}', '{{!COL5}}', '{{!COL6}}', '{{!COL7}}', '{{!COL8}}', '{{!COL9}}', '{{!COL10}}'"
SET col EVAL("var col=eval('[{{row}}]'); col[{{!VAR1}} - 1];")

EVENT TYPE=MOUSEUP POINT="(679,785)"
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#main>FOOTER>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)" CHARS={{col}}
```

Answer (score 1):

`SyntaxError: unterminated string literal` is likely a browser issue while parsing the code within the eval, for me your code works 100% out of the box.

Try line 12 like this (by removing `[`  `]`):

```
SET col EVAL("var col=eval('{{row}}'); col[{{!VAR1}} - 1];")
```

Else, run your code with a different browser/version.

Comment: still not work @Poyke I use another browser, i use FF last version.. but still same problem..